# Combining Concentration Inequalities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, concentration-of-measure

Let $(A_k)_{k \in I}, (B_k)_{k \in I}, (C_k)_{k \in I}, (D_k)_{k \in I}$ be sequences of random variables with $I$ being a finite index set. Assume we know the following concentration results:

1. $\mathbb{P}(|A_k - C_k| \geq \varepsilon) \leq K_k^{(1)}$ for all $k$
2. $\mathbb{P}(|B_k - D_k| \geq \varepsilon) \leq K_k^{(2)}$ for all $k$

where $K^{(1)}, K^{(2)}$ are constants depending on $k$ and $\varepsilon > 0$.

I would now like to get an uppper bound on
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\sum_{k\in I} A_k B_k - C_k D_k \right| \geq \varepsilon\right) \leq ??$$

Is there a way to use the two concentration results I have to get a decent bound? If we were not considering the measure, I don't see how I could split up the sum cleverly to to get the differences I know something about, but perhaps there is some property of the measure I could use that I have so far missed? Also, I feel like the finiteness of the index set and thus the sum is important, but I don't really know how to proceed.

Comment: Consider the matrix $\left[\begin{array}{cc}A_k&D_k\\C_k&B_k\end{array}\right].$ Its absolute value is the area of the parallelogram generated by $V_k=(A_k,C_k)$ and $W_k=(D_k,B_k)$ namely $\|V_k\|\times \|W_k\|\times \sin \theta_k$ where $\theta_k$ is small if $V_k$ and $W_k$ are close to the line $x=y.$

Comment: @GérardLetac thank you for your comment. However, I don't quite see how I can relate this back to the concentration inequalities I am given... and I think in my case it is not so easy to calculate the value of $\theta$.

Comment: The question seems very broad. First, is $(A_k)_{k\in I}$ independent? How does the right hand side of $\mathbb{P}(|A_k - C_k| \geq \varepsilon) \leq K_k^{(1)}$ depend on $\varepsilon$?

Comment: You are right, it is quite broad, the specific situation I am considering requires quite a lot of notation and introduction, so I tried to abstract it appropriately. However, maybe too much information was lost. The sequences are not independent, the right hand side is in my case roughly of the form $C\exp(-c \varepsilon^2 f(k))$ for positive constants $c, C$ and some function $f$ of $k$. I don't know if this helps though.